# Third party apps can't call applescript that otherwise work in 10.9

Tags: macos, applescript

I am invoking my apple script from third party executable(C executable).

Here is the applescript:

```
on run argv
    do shell script ("open -n /Applications/Test.app/ --args " & "'" & item 1 of argv & "' ")  
end run
```

It works fine in  mac version 10.9. I have write acces for this applescript. And i need to change this applescript for deletion of my temp files. But when i try to write some simple function inside this script, Its not working in 10.9 and works fine in 10.8 when invoked from third party executable.

Here is the sample for applescript simple function

```
display dialog "Message"
```

When i run this from applescript editor in 10.8 and 10.9, its works fine. Can someone please provide me a solution for the problem.

Comment: Above given do shell script function works fine in 10.9 mac version when i invoke from third party executable. Here i need to change this applescript for my deletion of temp files. But i worked lot for that. Even display dialog function is not getting called.

Comment: My guess is the sandboxing entitlements were less restrictive on 10.8. Without knowing what third party app is being used, we won't be able to guess the entitlements is has or even if it is signed code.

Comment: @bmike About the third party executable, it will create one temp files and surely it will invoke the apple script at last. I think control is over the applescript now. so can you please confirm this issue is due to third party sand boxed executable.

Comment: I can't confirm as I can't reproduce your issue. My suspicion is gatekeeper and the security might not even  allow an app to execute as you desire - even if you disable gatekeeper restrictions on the OS. My reasoning is if it were this trivial to get around sandboxing, there would be no fuss about Apple's control over what code can do since it would be a paper tiger.

Comment: Also - let me know if you want this to move to Stack Overflow. Unless you are OK with an answer about enabling or disabling gatekeeper or have some console log error that shows you have a permissions error this likely involves changes to the code of the third party tool and should be on stackoverflow.com

Comment: @santhosh how is the AppleScript being called by the application? Are you using `NSAppleScript` or another mechanism?

Comment: @GrahamMiln As i said it was third party executable. i don't have permission to view the source code. but surely it will call the applescript at the end. Don't know which mechanism they have used for invoking apple script.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if the application is invoking the `on run` handler, or maybe the application is calling the script by passing it to the shell, and thus expecting a hash-bang line such as `#!/usr/bin/osascript`.